# Computing partial derivatives for a function from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3 $ be defined as
$$
(u, v, w)=f(x,y,z) = (e^{2y} + e^{2z}, e^{2x} - e^{2z}, x - y)
$$
I have shown that it has differentiable inverse in a neighborhood of every point in $\mathbb{R}^3$. I want to compute
$$
\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}, \frac{\partial x}{\partial v}, \frac{\partial x}{\partial w}
$$
in terms of $x,y,z$. Based on the first part, I applied the Inverse Function Theorem and computed the inverse Jacobian
$$
\partial f^{-1}(u, v, w) = \frac{1}{2(e^{2x} + e^{2y})}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 2e^{2y} \\
1 & 1 & -2e^{2x} \\
e^{2x - 2y} & -e^{2y - 2z} & 2e^{2x+ 2y - 2z}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
However, I don't know how to proceed. What is $\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}$ anyway? Is it going to be number or a vector? All I can compute is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f^{-1}}{\partial u}$. Also the inverse Jacobian isn't even in terms of $u, v, w$. As you can tell I am really struggling to understand multivariable differentiation so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use
$$u=e^{2y}+e^{2z}$$
$$v=e^{2x}-e^{2z}$$
$$w=x-y$$
throughout, in this manner, for example
$u+v=e^{2x}+e^{2y}$,
etcetera.